# Hello, Problem witf Ubuntu 22 and Camera Monitor HPw2448hc

Tags: drivers, updates, hdmi, microphone, monitor

I upgraded my Ubuntu to 22 and now, I can´t use My Camera of a Monitor HP (connected via HDMI), Please ask for help, Thanks

I have problems with Mic too.

My PC is a Very old HP xw8400 Worstation, Video Power Color HD 5450 2GB. TX

Comment: Only by hdmi, or do you have a USB cable as well?

Comment: By Ubuntu 22 you mean Ubuntu Core 22 (ie. the *snap* only *flavor* of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server).  Ubuntu products using the *year* format (22) are different to those using the *year.month* format; the *year* being *snap* only and thus don't include `apt` commands.

Comment: Thanks vidarlo, I forgot to plug the usb cable,,,, Now, I Have camera and SHAME ja ja ja . Thank you